# Click on two buttons in the same time using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 buttons:

```html
<button onClick={click}>Click me</button>
<button>Click me</button>
```

How, clicking on `click` to click in the same time and second button?

Answer (score 2):

Select the second button element and use the `HTMLElement.click()` method to simulates a mouse click on that element.

Here is how you can do so with `React.useRef()`:

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  const secondButtonRef = React.useRef();
  const handleFirstButtonClick = () => {
    secondButtonRef.current.click();
  };
  const handleSecondButtonClick = () => {
    alert("Second button was clicked.");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleFirstButtonClick}>Click me 1</button>
      <button onClick={handleSecondButtonClick} ref={secondButtonRef}>
        Click me 2
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternatively, if you cannot attach React ref to the element, just use `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why would you do that but you can make your click handler call your click function twice or another function

```
<button onClick={() => {
click()
click()
}}>Click me</button>
<button onClick={() => {
click()
click()
}}>Click me</button>
```

If u really want to simulate a click on the second button, you can get a ref for that two buttons, and simulate a click using the `click` method on the dom node